# Uncaught ReferenceError in Cordova Connection

Tags: javascript, cordova, connection

The error above happens when I try to use Cordova's `checkConnection` function:

> cordova.js:29 Uncaught ReferenceError : require is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

```
function checkConnection()
{
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = "Unknown connection";
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = "Ethernet connection";
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = "WiFi connection";
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = "Cell 2G connection";
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = "Cell 3G connection";
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = "Cell 4G connection";
    states[Connection.CELL]     = "Cell generic connection";
    states[Connection.NONE]     = "No network connection";
    alert("Connection type: " + states[networkState]);
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to execute this function/code?

Comment: In a "onClick" event, and in a "deviceReady" and in "ng-click"

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by changing the `target` and `minimum-sdk` in `the config.xml`